# How to get the last time for each deviceid

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to get the last deviceTime for each unitid,heres the sql:

```
select d.name,d.uniqueid,d.category as 'Company',p.devicetime,p.latitude,p.longitude
 from devices d
INNER JOIN positions p
ON d.id = p.deviceid 
order By p.devicetime desc
limit 1,2
```

theres a wat to get the last devicetime for each uniqueid

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: removed `SQL Server` tag as there is no `limit` clause present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly modify your current query by doing an additional join to a subquery which identifies the most recent `devicetime` for each `uniqueid`:

```
SELECT d.name,
       d.uniqueid,
       d.category AS Company,
       p.devicetime,
       p.latitude,
       p.longitude
FROM devices d
INNER JOIN positions p
    ON d.id = p.deviceid 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.uniqueid, MAX(t2.devicetime) AS max_device_time
    FROM devices t1
    INNER JOIN positions t2
        ON t1.id = t2.deviceid
    GROUP BY t1.uniqueid
) t
    ON d.uniqueid   = t.uniqueid AND
       p.devicetime = t.max_device_time
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is in the `where` clause:

```
select d.name, d.uniqueid, d.category as Company,
       p.devicetime, p.latitude, p.longitude
from devices d join
     positions p
     on d.id = p.deviceid 
where p.devicetime = (select max(p2.devicetime)
                      from positions p2
                      where p2.deviceid = p.deviceid
                     )
order by p.devicetime desc
limit 1, 2;
```

For performance you want an index on `positions(deviceid, devicetime)`.